# Timing requirements in OPEN RAN/ORAN

Tags: network

I am looking for information about timing requirements in Open RAN, fronthaul, DU-RU.

What are the timing requirements?

Can I “ignore” it? In which scenarios can I ignore it?

What are the timing requirements if the distance between DU and RU is more than 1 km (space and ground)?

What Is the difference between timing requirements and synchronizations?